# How to properly handle closure in JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, events, svg, closures

I'm building my own class (for SVG objects) and have recently started adding event handling to it. Following standard model I'd like this type of interaction

```
svgobj.bind('click', function(e){
  // do stuff here on click with svgobj
});
```

*Even though I am using jQuery to attach events, this "bind" is not the jQuery `bind()` method and svgobj is not a jQuery object*

The problem I'm encountering is that if I create multiple objects then the `svgobj` reference inside that anonymous function is to the last `svgobj` created, instead of the one for which the event fired. So if my event takes care of changing the status of the object for example, no matter which object I click on, only the last object changes status.

I know this is a closure issue and with assistance from a colleague I found a fix, but it's a terribly ugly one. It involves wrapping the function in a self-executing anonymous function to which I pass the correct `svgobj` and which returns the original function, here's an example

```
svgobj.bind('click', (function(target){
    return function(e){
      // do stuff here on click with target, i.e. the correct svgobj
    }
  })(svgobj)
);
```

It works and you can see an example of this here http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/98te2/. You can test the dragging event (by the circle part) and the change status event by clicking the red/green area.

Is there a better way to resolve this issue? I'd like to avoid having to use two anonymous functions every time I want to do something on event. Perhaps there is a way to move the self-executing function into the method that calls the event in the first place, so that "on the outside" it still looks like just one regular function is being passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a pretty standard convention there, it would be considered fairly idiomatic javascript as is.

If you really want to make it cleaner, you could split out the anonymous function like this

```
function getCallBack(target){
   return function(e){
       //Do stuff with target
   }
}

svobj.bind('click',getCallBack(svobj));
```

That overall is longer, but it cleans up the bind call, and you can then add comments to clarify the use of the callback function.  Also useful if you are planning on reusing that code.

#### Update

Since it appears you are using a custom bind function, you can capture the original this value inside internal closures bysetting `` `var that = this; `` and then referencing `that` inside the internal functions. `that` will then always refer to the calling object, no matter how many levels of internal functions you use.

But since you're apparently using jQuery, I would recommend just using the jQuery bind function and making it easy on yourself.

Comment: That does make things neater and at least in one case it works out very well, but that still means that in those situations I need to write two functions for "one activity". I guess I'm trying to figure out how jQuery makes it so that when you do $(obj).('click', function(e){ this }); this ends up referring to obj and not the callback? (I've tried looking through jquery source but it's a bit over my head :-/)

Comment: if thats not the jQuery bind method is it a custom bind method? Its acting like the jQuery bind method, not like the native JS bind method.  If it is a custom method, you can get keep this at its original value inside enclosed functions by setting ```var that = this;``` and then referencing that inside the internal functions.

Answer (score 1):

By using [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (I'm assuming jQuery by how it is used), the `this` inside the *function* becomes the target, so there should be no need to use the variable `svobj` inside the function.

```
svgobj.bind('click', function (e) {
  // do stuff here on click with `this` or `$(this)`
});
```

In the case where you do want a copy of the current `svgobj` exactly as it is at `.bind` time, then you'll need to capture it in it's own scope to protect it from changes. The lambda function way you've described as "ugly" is most likely the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion but this is not the jQuery bind() method. I modified the question to clarify that point.